# How to make Clutterflow show automatically in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus-elementary, clutterflow, clutter

I'd like to know if Clutterflow can be enabled by default every time I open the Nautilus file manager.  It's a really good looking plug-in.

**Update:** In 11.04 The Icons shown by Clutterflow are corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made my own feature which shows it automatically.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1721799

Comment: ok i will give it a try

Comment: i'm there but...
Once opened you will see your category tree.. There is one called Other, click it and on the right you will see the one called Open Folder

Select it and right click>properties or Click properties on the right hand side and you will see a box where you can edit the launcher.

Comment: can't see that?

Comment: nevermind it was hidden..

Comment: ok one question, the script will only work IF i launch nautilus from that launcher?, for example if i use synapse to open a new nautilus window will it open with clutterflow enabled?

Comment: Well, if you just change the "file manager" launcher instead of the "open folder" one so it points to the sh file you created it should always launch nomatter what.. The file manager launcher is in the other category in my menu editor.

Answer (score 2):

According to a nautilus-elementary developer commenting on a similar question, this feature was in the [works](http://elementary-project.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1026&sid=aca937c8a7250fcbaedc95c394129e82#p1026), but given that nautilus-elementary development has [stopped](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/nautilus-elementary-is-dead-marlin-file-browser/) I don't think this feature will ever be added.

So in short, **No** you can not make Clutterflow open automatically everytime you open up Nautilus.