# How to enable clutter view default?

Tags: clutterflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Clutterflow show automatically in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13294/how-to-make-clutterflow-show-automatically-in-nautilus)

Can anyone help to enable the clutter by default whenever i open folders? it looks like i need to press F4 always to enable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mani

Comment: on 11.04 doesn't work btw.

Answer (score 2):

There is a thread on [ubuntu-forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1721799.html) asking just this - it appears that it is not possible as yet.

All credit to "fatriff" for providing a couple of workarounds:

Both involve using an extra package called `xdotool` which you can install as follows:

`sudo apt-get install xdotool`

**workaround 1**

- Using nautilus (file-manager), navigate to `/home/yourname/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`, right click in the folder and select create document>empty file.

In this file put the following..

```
#!/bin/sh
filesall=""
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
files=`echo "$1" | sed 's/ /\?/g'`
filesall="$files $filesall"
shift
done
nautilus $filesall
sleep 1
xdotool key F4
```

Now Save As clutterflow.sh

- Right click this file you just made and select Properties and then the Permissions tab and check the box.. Allow Executing file as Program..
- Goto your Main Menu and then Preferences and then find the Application called Main Menu.
- Once opened you will see your category tree.. There is one called Other, click it and on the right you will see the one called Open Folder
- Select it and right click>properties or Click properties on the right hand side and you will see a box where you can edit the launcher.
- Where is says command it currently says...

`nautilus --no-desktop %U`

Replace with this...

```
sh /home/yourname/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/clutterflow.sh
```

Don't forget to replace yourname in the line above with whatever name you use on your machine!

- Now press close and either click on a launcher you created or use the places menu or whatever you use..

**workaround 2**
For single launchers that only open 1 folder like Music or Videos etc.. just create a sh file called music.sh or videos.sh and use this instead.

```
#!/bin/sh
nautilus /home/yourname/Music
sleep 1
xdotool key F4
```

Remember to change yourname to your machines and Music to whatever folder you want..

Then create the launcher and change the name to match your sh script..

```
sh /home/yourname/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/music.sh
```